# Sklearn Confusion matrix only shows true positive and false positive

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a convolutional neural net for a binary classification and has the following details:

**Training Data:**

```
Class(0) : 5125 
Class(1) : 17098
```

**Test Dataset:**

```
Class(0) : 990 
Class(1) : 62556
```

After training my neural nets, I have built a confusion matrix(from sklearn.metrics) and found the result to be:

```
[[990       0  
 [62556     0]]
```

Is the model blindly predicting only positive class for every example? If it is the case, why is my accuracy showing 92%?

Comment: One of the measures is wrong. How do you calculate accuracy? According to matrix it is `(990 + 0) / (990 + 0 + 62556 + 0) == 990 / (990 + 62556) == 0.0156`

Comment: ok, but, is it normal that a confusion matrix doesn't show at least a true negative? Does that mean the model is not learning anything @hellpanderr